# Magento 2 : is there any way to change length of order id magento 2?

Tags: magento2

I just want to change order number's length in magento 2 , i have also tried with `increment_pad_length` in `eav_entity_type` table but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tried wrong way. **eav_entity_type** table not responsible for increment id in magento 2.

Magento 2 use **sales_sequence_profile** for doing that. If you want to change length then add following config inside di.xml, location **VendorName\ModuleName\etc\di.xml**

```
<type name="Magento\SalesSequence\Model\Sequence">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="pattern" xsi:type="string">%s%'.012d%s</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Comment: How can I use this for a particular store view?

Answer (score 0):

this work for both invoice and order id , what if i need different padding in both?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/200451)